# Problem running mercurial against symlinked .hgrc file under Cygwin/Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, symbolic-link, mercurial, dotfiles

This is not a question about handling symlinks in the mercurial repository.

I have this setup at work where I keep my dotfiles in a separate directory (`.configuration`) that I can use to synch my dotfiles between cygwin/windows and linux, then use symlinks instead of dotfiles in the home directory.

So, I have the symlink `~/.hgrc -> .configuration/.hgrc` in my home directory.  After setting this up, mercurial complains thus:

```
$ hg st
hg: config error at C:\Users\aaf\.hgrc:1: '!<symlink>ÿþ.configuration/.hgrc'
```

Removing the symlink and replacing it with the actual file works, so the contents of the `.hgrc` file are not at fault.  I can live with that, I suppose, but I'd like to know why this happens.  All other tools I've configured the same way work great with symlinked dotfiles.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot get this to work with a symlink, you might want to try a hardlink.
Then just make sure, when you edit the file, to change the contents of the file and not move a new one on top of the old, which breaks the hardlink.